# Preciso alterar um dado de uma tabela com informaçoes de uma outra tabela diferente

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tenho 2 tabelas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu preciso que sempre que for feito uma consulta ou inves de mostrar o `tagname` da tabela 2 seja apresentado os dados da coluna `mask` e sempre que for adicionado um novo `tagname` ele já atualize pra `mask`

Segue o código:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[historian]    Script Date: 19/09/2019 10:00:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[historian](
    [TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
    [TAGNAME] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [VALUE] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[historian] ([TIMESTAMP], [TAGNAME], [VALUE]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'BET', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[historian] ([TIMESTAMP], [TAGNAME], [VALUE]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-01T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'BET', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[historian] ([TIMESTAMP], [TAGNAME], [VALUE]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-01T02:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'BET', 3)
INSERT [dbo].[historian] ([TIMESTAMP], [TAGNAME], [VALUE]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'JAC', 11)
INSERT [dbo].[historian] ([TIMESTAMP], [TAGNAME], [VALUE]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-01T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'JAC', 22)
INSERT [dbo].[historian] ([TIMESTAMP], [TAGNAME], [VALUE]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-01T02:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'JAC', 33)
INSERT [dbo].[historian] ([TIMESTAMP], [TAGNAME], [VALUE]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SAO', 111)
INSERT [dbo].[historian] ([TIMESTAMP], [TAGNAME], [VALUE]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-01T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SAO', 222)
INSERT [dbo].[historian] ([TIMESTAMP], [TAGNAME], [VALUE]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-01T02:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SAO', 333)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.TAGNAME) 
            FROM historian as c 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT TIMESTAMP, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select TIMESTAMP
                    , VALUE
                    , TAGNAME
                from historian
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(VALUE)
                for TAGNAME in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

mas basicamente onde na tabela 1 se encontra o TAGNAME, no momento da consulta, eu preciso que ele retorne a informação da coluna MASK da tabela 2, quando for executado o pivot ao inves de aparecer os TAGNAME ele ira mostrar o MASK da tabela 2 no lugar do TAGNAME da tabela 1

Comment: Boas, apresenta uma tabela do teu resultado esperado com base no teu exemplo, para entender a tua necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando apenas as tabelas que você colocou na pergunta, já que seu comando SQL faz referencia a colunas que não existem nas tabelas apresentadas, nem precisa fazer uma junção, basta utilizar a tabela historian (a não ser que tenha ocorrido algum engano na pergunta):

```
SELECT DISTINCT mask FROM historian WHERE tagname = ?;
```

Não consegui entender a razão para as repetições. Erro de modelagem?